# Avoiding replay attacks on Resource Owner flow by using nonce

Tags: security, oauth, openid, native

I'm currently implementing an OpenID Connect authentication system for some apps I'm building, and one of the clients is a native mobile app. Having read about the different options for using OpenID Connect with a native client, it's clear that the current industry recommendation is to use the Hybrid Flow (i.e. show an embedded browser to collect the user's credentials, and then issue a token for the app to use). The alternative is to use the Resource Owner Flow, which has a better user experience in that the credentials are collected inside the app itself. But this seems to be discouraged for two main reasons:

1. It means that the native client will collect the credentials - so the native client has the opportunity to save the credentials or do something nefarious with them. In our case, we are creating the native client ourselves so this is not a concern. We will not be opening up the authentication system to other applications to use.
2. Because the Resource Owner Flow is from the OAuth 2 spec, rather than OpenID Connect, it lacks the replay attack prevention features of the other flows. Specifically, someone could record the authentication process, and then replay it themselves in order to obtain a user token from our identity server.

Since issue 1 is not a concern in our case, what I'd like to understand is whether there is a way to add replay attack prevention to the Resource Owner flow by using a nonce/temporary token of some kind. The scenario I'm thinking of is: the app would request a nonce from the identity server, which would include some sort of timestamp or other unique identifier for that request; the app would then need to provide that nonce with the authentication request; the identity server would validate the nonce before it allows the authentication request to be processed. That way, if someone was able to replay the entire message, the server would discover that the nonce is invalid and would reject the authentication request.

It's possible that an attacker could go and request a nonce from the server themselves, but then they would have needed to decrypt the (HTTPS) authentication request to be able to replace the original message's nonce with the new nonce they generated.

My questions are:

1. Are there any other reasons why the Resource Owner Flow is not a good idea in this situation?
2. If we did use the Resource Owner Flow, would a nonce approach like I described be a good way of avoiding replay attacks?